# Autodesk forge: Listing files and getting recent

Tags: autodesk-forge

I've been looking through the Autodesk Forge API a bit but I have not found a way to do the following things:

- Query/list files in a whole Fusion 360 team hub, filtering on e. g. filename.
- Get a list of the N most recently accessed files (created, opened, saved)

Is this possible? So far I've seen that is possible through recursion, but I want to avoid making a lot of API calls.

Answer (score 0):

> Query/list files in a whole Fusion 360 team hub, filtering on e. g. filename.

This can be done using the [search](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-search-GET/) endpoint. It traverses all subfolders recursively, and can filter based on different criteria (see https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/filtering/). I believe it can be used at a project level.

> Get a list of the N most recently accessed files (created, opened, saved)

I'm afraid this kind of sorting is not available using these endpoints.